# Parse PHP HTML Files into Database

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have app that needs to include searchable PHP Manual. Looking at Chmlib and time I have at hand, it looks I cannot make it by making CHM viewer. So I though I would find if I can get XML version of manul...none exists. As final resort I have decided I would use Python and beautifulsoup to parse files into database but then I ran into problem of knowing format that PHP Manual follow in documenting its functions and if the whole Idea I think is practical

Is this even possible in your opinion? Any pointer to help my mission? Is there any other way I can pack PHP documentation into database (like SQLite3)

Comment: it's definitely possible, but I think a better option may be to just include php manual from svn repository?

Comment: In which form is the manual in SVN? Can you drop me a link?

Comment: I'm checking out SVN to see if I can get anything useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used PHP XMLs from SVN as suggested by Paladin and from those DocBook XMLs I used PHP Manual builder script found in docs directory to configure and then build the format I need

check instructions in [PhD page](https://wiki.php.net/doc/phd#phd_--_building_the_php_manual_with_php)